# Computing Covariance of Sums of i.i.d. Random Variables

Tags: probability, solution-verification, covariance

**Problem:** Suppose that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. random variables with $E[X_1]=1$ and $E[X_1^2]=5$. Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Compute $\text{Cov}(S_a,S_b)$ for $1\leq a<b.$

**Attempt:** By the bilinearity of the covariance we have
$$\text{Cov}(S_a,S_b)=\sum_{i=1}^a\sum_{j=1}^b\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j).$$
Observe that if $i\ne j$ then since the random variables are i.i.d. we have
$$\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=E[X_iX_j]-E[X_i]E[X_j]=E[X_i]E[X_j]-E[X_i]E[X_j]=0.$$
On the other hand if $i=j$ then
$$\text{Cov}(X_i,X_i)=\text{Var}(X_i)=E[X_i^2]-E[X_i]^2=4.$$
Since $1\leq a<b$, it follows that
$$\text{Cov}(S_a,S_b)=\sum_{i=1}^a\sum_{j=1}^b\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=4a.$$

---

Could anyone help me verify if the calculation above is correct?
Thank you for your help and your time and really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been stated in the comments, your approach and result are correct.

That independence implies absence of correlation (and thus zero covariance) is a standard fact that you probably don’t have to show with an explicit calculation from the expectation values (but of course that depends on the context).